# AWS Java SDK: How to use AmazonDaxClientBuilder to replace regular DynamoDB client in 1.11.174 sdk version

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-java-sdk, amazon-dynamodb-dax

Looking at using DAX and the guides for the sdk seem to show various versions of the sdk, for example: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DAX.client.modify-your-app.html but these methods don't exist in the latest sdk 1.11.174 and if I build the client using AmazonDaxClientBuilder then I cannot pass this as the client as per the example.

Are there any up to date docs/examples or does anyone have an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the Java client is a separate jar, this is the library used in the examples, rather than the import of aws-java-sdk-dax.

Library available here but must be manually added to your project: http://dax-sdk.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/